# Nginx configuration issues

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, file-permissions

I'm having a lot of trouble getting my Nginx Website showing up correctly.

I've been getting `404` errors, and now i'm getting a `Connection Refused` error.

This is my **Nginx** configuration

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

It includes two other folders, **conf.d** is empty, and **sites-enabled** including Symbolic links to my Vhost configuration which is the following.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/subdomain.mydomain.com;
    index index.php;
    server_name subdomain.mydomain.com www.subdomain.mydomain.com;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~/\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

The **Root** folder referenced does exist and contains an **index.php** file which right now just echoes out a string.

The nginx error logs show only the following:

```
2016/11/24 22:35:40 [notice] 8834#8834: signal process started
2016/11/24 22:38:30 [notice] 8890#8890: signal process started
2016/11/24 23:13:48 [notice] 10108#10108: signal process started
2016/11/24 23:14:16 [notice] 10141#10141: signal process started
```

**PHP-FPM** is installed and the sock exists in the directory specified and FPM is in fact running, either way doesn't seem to be a **PHP** issue.

This leaves the configuration itself or **permissions** perhaps?

Like i said, my project is located in the /var/www directory

Permission for which look like this

```
drwxr-sr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 24 23:31 subdomain.mydomain.com
```

The index file inside of it:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myusername www-data 25 Nov 24 23:50 index.php
```

The sites are running in an AWS Instance.
I've already allowed port 80 in the security groups and access is set to be allowed from anywhere.

If anyone can help me out i'd very much appreciate it as i'm on my 3rd hour trying to figure this out... :(

Comment: I usually start by making sure nginx can server a plain HTML file to separate nginx issues from PHP issues.

Comment: @Paul i did that already, same result

Comment: Your firewall is configured to allow port 80?

Comment: Have you made sure your nginx is running?

Comment: @Paul i'm running on the site on an AWS server, the security groups are already set up to allow HTTP connections to port 80 from anywhere. 

It's a vanilla install i don't know of any additional firewalls.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen yes, nginx is running, if i type in `sudo service nginx status` it tells me that the service is indeed running

Comment: `drwxr-sr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Nov 24 23:31 subdomain.mydomain.com` - don't do this - the wordpress security model is not good, don't make it worse. While www-data needs write access to a lot of the files, you shouldn't be using the root account for normal maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `try_files` in your `location ~ \.php$` section. You just pass processing directly to the PHP-FPM process there.

Comment: @TeroKikanen thank you for your help, however changing that still results in ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED :(

I made the change you requested and then checked the validity of my nginx configs by running `sudo nginx -t` and finally ran `sudo service nginx reload` and `sudo service nginx restart` once i noticed the first command had not produced any changes. But still nothing by the end... :(

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out finally... i created my symlink wrong in Ubuntu for the sites-enabled folder.

I don't quite remember what i did wrong but a telltale sign the symlink is wrong is when it says you don't have permissions to edit it even with sudo. If that happens your symlink is wrong and you need to recreate it or else your sites won't work.

I hope my mistake can benefit someone in the future, thanks everyone for your help :)